# mongoDB search query for "dd/mm/yyyy" string date

Tags: mongodb, date, aggregate, nested-lists

I hold dates like 'dd/mm/yyyy' in MongoDB. I want to write a query that returns data between two dates.

I found querys but they are for ISO date or Unix Timestamp.

I wrote a query below, but it doesn't work healthy

```
db.getCollection('col_cost').aggregate([
{
               ......
                        "$match":{
                            "$and": [
                                {"$or":[  {  "costs.costDate": {
                                        $lte: '01/04/2021',
                                        $gte: '01/01/2021'
                                        }},
                                { "employeeID": 1)}
                            ]
                           ......
```

Example data:

[image]

Comment: Provide you whole query with example like you are getting the results and what you expect it to be.

Comment: Queries on date data stored as strings with format ""dd/mm/yyyy" wont work. Your query should convert the string to _Date_ format and then query against _Date_ fields. See the [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString) operator.

Comment: Storing date/time values as string is a design flaw. Store **always"" proper `Date` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the dates written as string in the nested document. First converts the string to iso. Then it filters the iso date information.

```
db.getCollection('col_cost').aggregate([

  { "$addFields": {
      "costs": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$costs",
          "in": {
            "$mergeObjects": [
              "$$this",
              {
                "costDate": {
                  "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": ["$$this.costDate", ""] },
                    null,
                    { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$$this.costDate", "format": "%d/%m/%Y" } }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  {
    "$unwind" : "$costs"
  },
  {
    "$match":{
      "employeeID": ObjectId("5d89ca44cf4df62bddd64cf2"),
      "$and": [
        {"$or":[
            {
              "costs.status":"completed"
            }
          ]},

        { "costs.costDate": {
            $gte: ISODate("2019-12-01T21:00:00Z"), //start,
            $lte:  ISODate("2022-12-21T21:00:00Z") //end
          }},


      ]
    }
  }

])
```